# tablet won't recognize usb keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

Azpen tablet android 4.2.2 won't recognize my usb keyboard. I downloaded external keyboard and a usb host controller and it doesn't work. I connected it to my pc and the keyboard works just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Azpen tablet? Azpen is the name of [the manufacturer](http://azpenpc.com/index.html) and they sell several tablets.

Comment: It's possible that this tablet simply doesn't support USB host mode. If the hardware doesn't support it, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Azpen A727 tablet, I just got one of them for $20 through a Micro Center promotion.  The device FAQ states it can't use an external keyboard.

One thing you can try is turning on USB debug mode.  To do so, invoke the Settings app, scroll down to and tap About Tablet.  At the bottom of the About Tablet display, tap Build Number multiple times.  You'll see a message indicating progress, and at the end you'll be told you are a developer.  Once successful, there will be a {} Developer Options menu entry added to the System section of the Settings app, and you can turn on USB debugging from there.

It may also be possible to enable this if you root the device.  I found instructions for doing so at http://zepinventory.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/how-to-root-azpen-a727-tablet/  (It's Windows only.)  I haven't been able to make it work yet, but that's likely because I was trying it from an XP box, and will try again from the SO's Win7 laptop.

It's also possible that USB host mode is simply not present.  The Azpen docs say communication is one way - you can connect the tablet to a PC and get stuff *from* the tablet *to* the PC, but *not* vice versa.  When I connect it to the PC here, the PC sees two removable drives, but neither can be accessed as it doesn't think there is media in the drives.

I'd like to use it with an external keyboard, but I'll live if I can't.  What it does now is more than worth what I paid for it.

Update: Rooting the device removed the restriction.  Once rooted, the device recognized my Logitech Portable keyboard, and a Logitech entry appeared in Settings allowing me to select the preferred keyboard layout. I found a guide to rooting that I followed here: http://zepinventory.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/how-to-root-azpen-a727-tablet/

Comment: I have the same tablet and when I connect it to a Windows 8.1 PC it shows up as 2 drives, the "sd card" (really extra internal memory) and the "external sd card" (one that I plugged in).  I can demonstrably transfer data both ways.  My tablet is not yet rooted.